# derivative of a polynomial at a point

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $P(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial such that $P(n)=P(-n)$ for all natural number $n$. Then $P'(0)=?$. I thought that polynomial is continuous function with the given property is constant function, may be wrong. thanks in advance.

Comment: There are lots of polynomial with the given property.  $P(x)=x^2, x^4,x^{2n}$ all work.

Comment: Consider the polynomial $Q(x)=P(x)-P(-x)$. This vanishes on all natural numbers. Therefore it is identically zero. Taking derivatives we get $0=Q'(x)=P'(x)+P'(-x)$. Evaluating at $x=0$ we get $0=2P'(0)$. Therefore, $P'(0)=0$.

Comment: @Marja, please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, if a function $f$ is even, that is,
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
then, by the chain rule,
$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)$$
and its derivative is odd. Furthermore, if a function $g$ is odd, then
$$g(x)=-g(-x)$$
$$g(0)=-g(-0)$$
$$g(0)=-g(0)$$
$$2g(0)=0$$
$$g(0)=0$$
Using these two simple facts, you can easily solve your problem.

Comment: Why the given polynomial is even ? He has only $P(-n)=P(n)$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: @Houssam It makes little difference, since $0$ is (sometimes?) a natural number.

Comment: @Houssam If two *polynomials* agree on an infinite set then they are equal (else there difference would be a nonzero polynomial with infinitely many roots).

Comment: @BillDubuque Your remark is important, but I can't see how we can  use it to prove that $P$ is even.

Comment: @Houssam It shows that $\,P(x)-P(-x) = 0,\,$ since it is a *polynomial* with infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$P(n)=a_0n^{2k}+a_1n^{2(k-1)}+\cdots +a_{k-1}n^2+a_k, a_0,...,a_k\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Then:
$$P'(n)=2ka_0n^{2k-1}+2(k-1)a_1n^{2(k-1)-1}+\cdots+2a_{k-1}n.$$
Hence:
$$P'(0)=0.$$